# Program License Agreement update agreed upon, however, still encounter 'An unspecified error occurred

Tags: xcode6, iphone-developer-program

I have clicked tick and agreed on the program license agreement update, however returning back to my provisioning ID and certificates, a pop-up error occurs "An unspecefied error occurred. The selected team's agent, must agree to the latest Program License Agreement. Please visit the Member Center.

Comment: having same problem. ever resolve this?

Comment: No havent resolved this issue yet. @brendonparker